# Append styling to a iFrame #document element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm kind of stuck and I'm looking to see if anyone could give me some assistance, so I have the following jQuery code:

```
let VimeoBlock = function($element) {
    function init() {
        adjustPositioning();
    }

    function adjustPositioning() {
        const classList = $element.attr('class');
        if (classList.indexOf('alignwide') > -1) {
            const vimeo_iframe = $element.find('iframe');
            console.log(vimeo_iframe);
        }
    }

    return {
        init: init,
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wp-block-embed-vimeo').each(function (i, ele) {
        (new VimeoBlock($(ele))).init();
    });
});
```

`console.log(vimeo_iframe);` outputs the following items when I can access the `iFrame` index with its properties:

[image]

I'm able to target the `iFrame`, but I want to be able to target the parent class inside the `iFrame` - How would I go about doing this and appending CSS to that class?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you can only target the iframe element itself (border, margin, etc) but not any of the content (inside html) unless its from the same domain due to security issues.

Comment: If the iframe is on a different origin you won't be able to access the its DOM. See: [Cross-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: It's not on the same domain, I was hoping I can target the parent class because it has crucial width specifications and I wanted to overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot do this for the styling of the iframe if it's on a different origin, there is no solution in this case. However, if it was the same domain or an `iframe` with an inner structure, then you could do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("youriframeid").contentDocument.querySelector("yourselector").style.display = 'none';
```

Note that I have used dummy selectors and a dummy styling, you can use yours instead.